# EasyJSWebView gives EXEC_BAD_ACCESS code 1 while returning long string from objective c function

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

I am using **EasyJSWebView** github project to call objective c functions from javascript. I have created one objective C method which returns long string. For small length strings it works properly.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Where does arrived the error? What's your code? Did you activated NSZombies? Did you locate the line of the error? Did you check if an object at nil (already released) was used?

Comment: actually i'm new to objective c. I don't know how to use and activate NSZombies. How to locate line of error? please help me.